# Applying a show/hide class div to every div with different content

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip, fadein

This is probably a simple question but after trying a few methods i need some advice.

I have some divs that when you hover over them, will show another div (acting like a tooltip) with different content for each div. The jsFiddle i have provided shows an example of it on the red div. What i am trying to achieve through jQuery is when you hover over any other div show that divs content.

At the moment, i have 2 divs (blue and red) and can only get it to work with the red with the jQuery provided. How would this work for multiple divs?

I would have easily used a tooltip plugin however i am using this example in anther plugin and they conflict very bad with tooltips inside the slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/DeRx8/1/

```
 $('.red').hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip").fadeIn(250);
    }, function () {
        $(".tooltip").fadeOut(250);
    });
```

If anyone can guide me where to start that would be great.

Thanks

PS * I am going to have over 10 divs red, bluc, pink, green ect..

Comment: can't you add a common class to all of them? something like class="red showtip", class="blue showtip", class="pink showtip" and then any of the $(this).next() functions will work and you can add more colors as necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.red,.blue').hover(function () {        
        $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeToggle(250);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sq5nP/

If you want to position the tooltip via css you can use the `+` adjacent selector if your tooltip will always be the next sibling

```
.red+.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background-color:#993;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:60px;
    top:40px;
}
.blue+.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background-color:blue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:170px;
    top:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyrp7/

Answer (score 3):

With multiple selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.red, .blue').hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip").fadeIn(250);
    }, function () {
        $(".tooltip").fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DeRx8/2/)

Comment: Thats great but both of the div's show the 'blue box information' rather than the red div with red info and blue with blue info :) Your demo does make sense though!

Comment: You can get  the selector by $(this).. based on that you can show where you exactly need.

Comment: So is there no short way of writing the code for this?: http://jsfiddle.net/DeRx8/4/ thanks for the response guys

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.red,.blue').hover(function () {
    $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeOut(250);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DeRx8/3/
UPDATE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.red,.blue').hover(function () {
    var left=$(this).offset().left+$(this).width()-40;
    $(this).next(".tooltip").css("left",left).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeOut(250);
});
});
```

position .tooltip
http://jsfiddle.net/DeRx8/5/

Comment: Your answer is correct but after looking at the code i may have to alter it, you see i need the blue tooltip hover div to be positioned next to it so it means styling different toolbox classes?

Comment: you have position absolute so all the .tooltip have the same position, you can change the HTML or set the position with jQuery

Comment: @user2212564 you can do that via css using the adjacent selector if they are always the next sibling http://jsfiddle.net/yyrp7/

Comment: ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ your example is spot on to what i was after if you put this in a post rather than comment i can tick it :) Everyone else answers were great too +1